# Only add unique elements to arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist, bufferedreader

I am currently writing a java program that takes data from a text file and adds to to an array list. My problem is, that every time I run the program, the arraylist keeps updating and has duplicate elements - I would like each element to only appear once.

`

```
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("s.txt"));
        for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
            if(!listID.contains(Integer.parseInt(line))){
            listID.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
            }
            for(int i=0;i<listID.size();i++){
                // do stuff
            }
```

`

I have tried to use does not contain but it isnt working.

Comment: Then use a Set.

Comment: Add all your elements to a Set, then add them to a List to get the final data structure you need.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're doing -- why is the second loop nested in the first?

Comment: Your code should already work -- your "duplicates" are probably from your incorrect loop nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet(); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("s.txt"));

for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
     set.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
     for(int i=0;i<listID.size();i++){
         // do stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! In the "do stuff" part I was planning on accessing specific elements of the arraylist but I'm not sure if you would be able to do that with a set?

Comment: Sure, you could user iterator. And travel through it.

Comment: The difference with a set is that it will not preserve the order of the elements, unless you use a `LinkedHashSet`